# Concatenating string with each row in data frame and applying function to them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains all sort of data -- string,int and date object too.

I already have apiece of code `(deal_value(val))` that identifies the type of val and makes it a string. I need to be able to apply that to all the cells in the dataframe I have right now.

After that, I need to concatenate the row value with the row name in the dataframe.

I looked at apply function for both of these but was unable to figure out how to use it in either case

---

Dataframe Examples:

```
     name    age    dob
0    A        10    20-Jun-1969
```

And I want the dataframe to be:

```
    name         age         dob
0    A name     10 age      20-Jun-1969 dob
```

My function deal_value would take each cell element and make them good to concatenate into a string,
so ultimately I want it to be something like:

```
"A name, 10 age,20-Jun-1969 AND (row-2) AND (row-3)......."
```

Comment: Some sample input and output would help. Please see [how to create a good pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide a [mcve] for your task

Comment: by row name you mean column name ?

Comment: @KaiesLAMIRI that is correct.

Comment: @piRSquared but it's not concatenating the column name yet, is it?

Comment: @user11638578 no. I missed that

Comment: and it's also getting the index in .. i.e. 0 and so on.. can I just remove the first index and move on?

Comment: @user11638578 so you want to concatenate each row into a single string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'name': 'A', 'age': 10, 'date_of_birth': '20-Jun-1969'}, index=[0])

for col in list(df.columns): 
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([str(col), str(x)]))


df.head()
```

Output

```
    name     age        date_of_birth
0   name A   age 10     date_of_birth 20-Jun-1969
```

String Output :

```
df_to_string = df.to_string(header=False,
                            index=False,
                            index_names=False).split('\n')
vals = [ ', '.join(element.lstrip().rstrip().split('  ')) for element in df_to_string]
vals_str = ' And '.join(vals)

print(vals_str)
```

Output:

```
'name A, age 10, date_of_birth 20-Jun-1969 And name B,  age 5, date_of_birth 21-Jun-1969'
```

Comment: how would I go about concatenating it now in a string without the row number?

Comment: @user11638578 I just edited the answer for you :), happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you just need:

```
df.astype(str).add(' '+df.columns)
```

---

```
     name     age              dob
0  A name  10 age  20-Jun-1969 dob
```

Comment: Wow this is huge, I like it but the only thing here is that if there are null values you would still stringify them

Comment: @KaiesLAMIRI if i understand the question, everything will be `object` dtype? since you are adding the col names anyway..?

Comment: Yes ! correct but, I mean with this solution you have less flexibility in dealing with non common cases .. but I appreciate your solution btw !!

Comment: @KaiesLAMIRI The OP hasn't specified any non-common cases to be taken care of. i would have taken a different approach then. Anyways, up-voted your's sol.

Comment: up-voted yours too ! yes I am just talking from a pythonic perspective :)